# R: Title of graphs is missing half its text

Tags: r

```
#Stock Price
PSXPrice0 <- read.table("PSXPrice.csv", header=TRUE, sep= ",")
PSXPrice <- PSXPrice0[,c(1, 5)]
myOrder1 <- order(PSXPrice$Date, decreasing = FALSE)
PSXPrice1 <- PSXPrice[myOrder1,]
PSXPrice1$Date <- as.Date(PSXPrice1$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
plot(Close ~ Date,PSXPrice1, type = "o", main="Stock Price")

#Volume 
PSXVol <- PSXPrice0[,c(1, 7)]
myOrder2 <- order(PSXVol$Date, decreasing = FALSE)
PSXVol1 <- PSXVol[myOrder2,]
PSXVol1$Date <- as.Date(PSXVol1$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
plot(Volume ~ Date,PSXVol1, type = "o", main = "Volume")

#High Minus Low Price
PSXHigh.Low <- PSXPrice0[,c(1, 3, 4)]
PSXHigh.Low$HighLow <- (PSXHigh.Low$High)-(PSXHigh.Low$Low)
myOrder3 <- order(PSXHigh.Low$Date, decreasing = FALSE)
PSXHigh.Low1 <- PSXHigh.Low[myOrder3,]
PSXHigh.Low1$Date <- as.Date(PSXHigh.Low1$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
plot(HighLow ~ Date,PSXHigh.Low1, type = "o", main = "High Minus Low Price")

#Graph layout
par(mfrow=c(2,2),mar = c(1,1,1,1), oma=c(0,0,2,0))

#Correlation between stock price and volume
PSXData0 <- read.table("PSXPrice.csv", header=TRUE, sep= ",")
ccf(PSXData0$Volume, PSXData0$Close, 25)
myCoef1 <- coef(summary(lm(PSXData0$Volume ~ PSXData0$Close)))
plot(PSXData0$Close, PSXData0$Close * myCoef1[2,1] + myCoef1[1,1], type="l", main = c("T-Value", round(myCoef1[2,3], 3)))
points(PSXData0$Close, PSXData0$Volume, main = c("T-Value", myCoef[2,3]))

#Correlation between high minus low stock price and volume
PSXHigh.Low <- PSXData0[,c(1, 3, 4)]
PSXHigh.Low$HighLow <- (PSXHigh.Low$High)-(PSXHigh.Low$Low)
ccf(PSXData0$Volume, PSXHigh.Low[,4], 25)
myCoef2 <- coef(summary(lm(PSXData0$Volume ~ PSXHigh.Low[,4])))
plot(PSXHigh.Low[,4], PSXHigh.Low[,4] * myCoef2[2,1] + myCoef2[1,1], type="l", main = c("T-Value", round(myCoef2[2,3], 3)), xlab = "Difference between High and Low Stock Price in One Month", ylab = "Volume")
points(PSXHigh.Low[,4], PSXData0$Volume)
```

All the data is from https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PSX/history?period1=1340578800&period2=1498345200&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo. I'm not quite sure how to attach a file from my computer (I imagine that would be easier for people).

I Think it has something to do with par(mfrow= ) but I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

[image: Here is the result when I run the code, as you can see the title "t value... " is missing its top half]

Comment: We can't run this without your data file. Please make an example that illustrates the problem using data we can either all get or generate some random data.

Comment: What are those mar and oma parameters doing? Why did you set them to what they are? Do you understand them? Have you tried changing them?

Comment: Sorry, I realise I've been a bit stupid! I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: I've edited the post to include more information. Is this better?